# Android Ble disconnect time delay

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I wrote some code  to connect my android phone to a ble device. When I power off the ble device my phone takes a few seconds (2-20s) to notify me that it has lost connection to the ble device. Is there a way I can be notified right away? can I change the Connection supervision timeout?

Comment: that's what i want to know very badly...

Comment: @David- this issue was fixed by changing code on the Ble device side. I didnt make a change to my android code.

Comment: how did you changed code on ble device? Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

When Ble device sends disconnects cmd , it waites for ack from android app. If ACK is received it will disconnect instantly,if not it will wait till supervision timeout occurs.Usually on connection with Android app, the ble device(peripheral) has to adhere to app(central) Connection Parameters (Connection Interval, Latency , supervision timeout). 
The supervision timeout in Android is hardcoded to 20 seconds ,due to which we get 20sec delay in disconnection([Referrence](https://blog.classycode.com/a-short-story-about-android-ble-connection-timeouts-and-gatt-internal-errors-fa89e3f6a456))
To solve this issue I sent a Connection Parameters Update Request from BLE Device after 5seconds on connection updating the Supervision Timeout to 1sec. I tested with few android devices and found that the delayed in disconnections was solved.